# If $f'(z)$ exists does this mean that $f'(\bar{z})$ exists?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we know that a complex function $f$ is differentiable in some region, $D$. Then how can we show that $f'(\bar{z})$ also exists?

I tried using the definition of the derivative:

$$f'(\bar{z}) = \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\bar{z}+h)-f(\bar{z})}{h}$$ and then relating this to the limit for $f'(z)$ but I haven't gotten very far with that. How should I proceed?

Comment: Why should $\bar z$ belong to $D?$

Comment: By Schwarz reflexion principle, maybe ?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable in $D$ then $f($insert symbol here$)$ exists whenever insert symbol here $\in D$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. Let $f : D \to D$ be the identity function. Then $f$ is differentiable, but $f(\overline{z})$ is the conjugation map, which is not (complex) differentiable.

EDIT: I assumed by $f'(\overline{z})$, you meant $\frac{d}{dz} f(\overline{z})$. If you actually mean $f'(\overline{z})$, then that is a function on $\overline{D} = \{ \overline{z} : z \in D \}$. Since $f'$ exists, the expression $f'(\overline{z})$ is defined for each $z \in \overline{D}$.

Comment: But he's talking about $f'(\bar z),$ not the derivative of $ f(\bar z).$

Comment: Yeah, his notation says $f'(\tau(z))$, where $\tau$ is conjugation, but his limit expression for the derivative suggests he means $(f \circ \tau)'(z)$.

EDIT: wait no it doesn't. Oops. I'm no longer sure what the OP wants.